# Create a Timeline Query with date periods in SQL ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to write a Query in SQL Access (no choice with the software...) in order to create a timeline from a Table of records. 
Hereunder a simple example in order to explain what I want to do.

I have a table with 2 records. Each record is defined by its ID, a Value, a date of begin, a date of end and a Level of confidence.

```
Id | vValue |  dtBegin |   dtEnd  | lLevel
-------------------------------------------
1  |    a   |20/06/2016|28/06/2016|   Low
2  |    b   |23/06/2016|25/06/2016|   High
```

The query should return a timeline with the highest level of information (and its value) available for each period of time. In the example the result of the query should be:

```
vValue|  dtBegin |  dtEnd   |lLevel
------------------------------------
  a   |20/06/2016|23/06/2016|  Low
  b   |23/06/2016|25/06/2016|  High
  a   |25/06/2016|28/06/2016|  Low
```

From the 20/06/2016 to the 23/06/2016 the highest level of confidence available in the table is 'Low' and the associated value is 'a'/

From the 23/06 to the 25/06, the period is covered by two records but the highest level of confidence available is 'High', therefore the value is 'b'

Thanks a lot for your help

Thibaud

Comment: Do you have some SQL you could show?

Comment: @MattCremeens No I do not have anything... I am not sure where to start...

Comment: If you could at least get started on something, you will greatly increase your chances of help.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm going to try to post something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be an easier way of doing it, you could start with a base query to get all dates necessary:

```
SELECT dtBegin
FROM Table1
GROUP BY dtBegin 

UNION 
SELECT dtEnd AS dtBegin 
FROM Table1
```

With this query you can get the non-overlapping date ranges:

```
SELECT Timeline.dtBegin, Min(Timeline_1.dtBegin) AS dtEnd 
    FROM Query1 AS Timeline, Query1 AS Timeline_1
    WHERE (((Timeline_1.dtBegin) > Timeline.dtBegin))
    GROUP BY Timeline.dtBegin
```

From this you could cross join back to your original table, and get the max level and vValue for any table entry that overlaps the date range using a subquery:

```
SELECT Query2.dtBegin, Query2.dtEnd, Table1.lLevel, Table1.vValue 
FROM Query2, Table1
WHERE (((Table1.lLevel) =
    (SELECT MAX(lLevel) 
     FROM Table1 T 
     WHERE T.dtBegin <=Query2.dtBegin AND 
         T.dtEnd >=Query2.dtEnd))) AND
    ((Table1.dtBegin)<=Query2.dtBegin) AND 
    ((Table1.dtEnd)>=Query2.dtEnd)
```

You'll have to do some extra logic to get a max level, of course, depending on how your choices are configured.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without seeing the data structure. If the begin / end dates don't overlap in your data this could possibly work:

```
/* Finds distinct dates which only have a low record */

SELECT
    vValue,dtBegin,dtEnd,'Low' AS lLevel
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT vValue,dtBegin,dtEnd
    FROM tbl
    WHERE lLevel = "Low"
    EXCEPT
    SELECT DISTINCT vValue,dtBegin,dtEnd
    FROM tbl
    WHERE lLevel = "High"
 ) AS X
/* Appends distinct date sets */
UNION   
SELECT DISTINCT vValue,dtBegin,dtEnd,lLevel
FROM tbl
WHERE lLevel = "High"
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, but the fact is the dates overlap. That is the main issue of my query request

Comment: To clarify, this code would work fine if there are overlapping high/low confidence levels within the same date range. It would not work if there were date ranges which overlapped part of another date range. e.g. 1/3/16 - 1/5/16 and 1/4/16 - 1/6/16 would cause confusion.